# Passing arguments to encapsulated in object jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Learning on CodeSchool, they advice to store functions in objects and to call them later.

That works absolutely fine until I want to pass an argument to the function. At this point, I'm lost with either the syntax or the logic behind.

A sample code is worth a thousand words :

```
var subscriptionMaster = {
    init: function() {
        $('.choose_offer').on('click', this.toggleOfferClass);
        $('.nextFirstPage, .nextSecondPage, .prevThirdPage, li:not(".firstLink")').on('click', this.changeDisplayTransForm('none', false);
        $('.prevSecondPage, .firstLink').on('click', this.changeDisplayTransForm('block', true);
    },

    toggleOfferClass: function(event) {
    $('.choose_offer').removeClass('active');   
    $(this).addClass('active');
    },

    changeDisplayTransForm: function(sState, bVerifyStep1) {
        $('#transformClientToMaster').css('display', sState);

        if (bVerifyStep1) {
            if ($('#step1_done').val() != '1') {
            changeDisplayTransForm(sState); 
            }
        }
    }
};
```

this :

```
$('.choose_offer').on('click', this.toggleOfferClass);
```

is working fine, while this :

```
$('.nextFirstPage, .nextSecondPage, .prevThirdPage, li:not(".firstLink")').on('click', this.changeDisplayTransForm('none', false);
$('.prevSecondPage, .firstLink').on('click', this.changeDisplayTransForm('block', true);
```

does not work at all.

Any help ?

Comment: At the very least you're missing a `)` on those last two statements. You can use `bind` on those two to get what you want.

Comment: in second case you not pass function, just call it immediately

Comment: Andy, how do I use bind ?
Tried this :
  `$('.nextFirstPage, .nextSecondPage, .prevThirdPage, li:not(".firstLink")').on('click', this.changeDisplayTransForm.bind('none',false));`
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard first parameter for [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is _thisArg_, so just add it like `this.changeDisplayTransForm.bind(this, 'none',false)`